# How to get view path in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Codes:

```
<?php 
$view_path = Config::get('view.paths'); 
echo $view_path[0]; 
?>
```

Result:

```
D:\wamp\www\teaspoon_cms\system\resources\views
```

My browsers do not like the path that view.paths returns. Why does it return a file path instead of a URI? What can I do to fix this? I want it be like this

```
http://localhost/teaspoon_cms/system/resources/views
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Your view path is not to be reached from your browser, so, why do you need it?

Answer (score 3):

The `resources` folder is not supposed to be accessible via the browser. 
Only files inside of the `public` folder are supposed to be accessible this way.

So:

- everything in the `public` folder you can access via http://
- everything outside your `public` folder you will have to access via the file path.